# I can not get the value of a textbox on a view in mvc 4 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
@model IEnumerable<TBWeb.Models.SP_GetALlRoutes_Result>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Rutas";

    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

   string fecha=string .Empty ;
 }


<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
    $('#FechaInicio').onchange(function (){

     fecha= document.getElementById("FechaInicio").value;

    )};
  </script>


<input type="text" id="FechaInicio">
```

Comment: Este es mi textbox  <input type="text" id="FechaInicio">

Comment: Your code is logically flawed. `string fecha = string.Empty;` is a C# variable, but `fecha` inside the JavaScript block is a JavaScript variable. You cannot assign from JavaScript to C# because the C# runs at the server and is gone by the time the client side runs the JavaScript.

Comment: how can i  get this value in my  variable???

Comment: Do you want the variable to be sent back to the server or just available in JavaScript?

Comment: i want  to send the value of my variable as parameter to call a controller that need this value.

Comment: if i use runat server on my textbox, how do i call the textbox in the server side???

Comment: runat server is for webforms. You are using MVC. You should put the input element in a form and post that form to your controller. See http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started for an example of creating your first MVC app

Comment: Thanks, i will check the link

Answer (score 0):

```
@model IEnumerable<TBWeb.Models.SP_GetALlRoutes_Result>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Rutas";    
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }

<input type="text" id="FechaInicio">

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
$(function() { //wait for doc ready before trying to wire up to element

    //use jquery event handler for text change: 'input' event is an on change event 
    $('#FechaInicio').on('input', function (){

       var inicio = $(this).val();//this refers to the FechaInicio element the input event fired on

       //send to controller action
      $.ajax({
        url: @Url.Action("SomeActionName"),
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 
          whateverParamNameIsIncontrollerAction: inicio 
        },
        success: function (result) {
           //do whatever after request completes
        }
      });//ajax           

    )};//on input

)};//doc ready
</script>
```